# Website scrolling horizontally for unknown reason

Tags: html, css, drupal

The URL: http://pipedvan.com/

The website seems to have extra spacing to the right which is causing the horizontal scrollbar to show up, I'm not sure where this problem lies but help is greatly appreciated!

PS. It is showing up in Firefox, Chrome & IE9 .. and I've only noticed it on the Home Page. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to remove width: 100% on: #ddblock-custom-pager-1

```
div.ddblock-cycle-sardinia div.custom-pager /* on line 1076 of your style1.css*/
```

100% is relative to the parent container, so you move your element to the right it will blow your design up.