# width=100% on H1 is causing extra margin-right on body canvas ...?

Tags: css

I'm working with Chrome/Firefox on a Mac. Have a look at [this page](http://www.amordetango.nl/txp/) please.

There is a horizontal scrollbar and so on the right there is extra margin. Sniffing around on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166552/website-scrolling-horizontally-for-unknown-reason) I discovered that it has something to do with width=100% on H1 (H2) ... because skipping it the extra margin disappears ... :) ... but now the H1 is at the left and that is not what I want ... :(

```
header 
{
    background-color: #73020c;
    padding-bottom: 110px; /* to push .banner down */
}

hgroup 
{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center; /* to center h1 en h2 */
    z-index: 1;
}

h1 
{
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -50%; /* half the width */
    z-index: 2;
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    padding-left: 0.15em; /* to compensate letter-spacing h1 */
}

h2 
{
    font-family: 'MutluOrnamental', sans-serif;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #b7b7b7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -50%; /* half the width */     
    z-index: 3;
    padding-top: 10px; /* !important > to make h2 fit in relation to h1 */
}

/* for all browser including all IE! */
h2 {
    opacity: 0.75;
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested this in Safari (which shows the same issue since it's also based on Web kit).

I fixed it as follows:

```
h1 
{
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I've removed the -50% method of centering so that the block isn't pushed off the page (causing the issue) and dropped back to text-align: center. I've also had to remove this line:

```
padding-left: 0.15em; /* to compensate letter-spacing h1 */
```

But visually, to my eye, that causes no problems.

Tim

Comment: @Tim ... thanks for pushing me further ... :)  It is (of course) the padding-left that causes the extra margin. So I thought: Can I use `box-sizing: border-box;` here? Yes, I can ... :)

Answer (score 0):

So H1 has to be extended with `box-sizing`:

```
h1 
{
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -50%; /* half the width */
    z-index: 2;
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    padding-left: 0.15em; /* to compensate letter-spacing h1 */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* content-box */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

... and there is a [polyfill](http://css3clickchart.com/#box-sizing) too ... :)